# Time complexity of $(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, svd

Assume that there is a block matrix $I\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ that can be partitioned into

$$
I=\begin{pmatrix}
    A & B  \\
    C & D  \\
    \end{pmatrix}\,,
$$

where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{p_1\times p_1}\,$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{p_1\times p_2}\,$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{p_2\times p_1}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{p_2\times p_2}$ with $p=p_1+p_2\,$.

I know that the inversion of $I$ via SVD is $\mathcal{O}(p^3)\,$. Now I am interested in the following two inversions:

$$
(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}
$$

and

$$
D^{-1}\,.
$$

The following are my steps to compute the time complexity:

1. Computing $D^{-1}$ costs $\mathcal{O}(p_2^3)\,$;
2. Computing $BD^{-1}$ costs $\mathcal{O}(p_1p_2^2)\,$;
3. Computing $BD^{-1}C$ costs $\mathcal{O}(p_1^2p_2)\,$;
4. Computing $A-BD^{-1}C$ costs $\mathcal{O}(p_1^2)\,$;
5. Computing $(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$ costs $\mathcal{O}(p_1^3)\,$.

Thus, the overall complexity is

$$
\mathcal{O}(p_1^3+p_2^3+p_1^2+p_1^2p_2+p_1p_2^2)\,,
$$

which costs less than inverting $I$ with $\mathcal{O}(p^3)=\mathcal{O}\left((p_1+p_2)^3\right)\,$?

Could anyone please check if what I did above are correct or not?

Comment: why don't you break it down into steps and indicate what you think is the time complexity for each step?

Comment: @LinAlg Done so above, could you please have a check? Thanks!

Comment: Matrix multiplication can be implemented [more efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm), but I do not think that is relevant for the answer because the terms in the overall complexity are dominated by the first two terms, so you can leave out the last 3 terms. That means that both complexities are of the same order (although that doesn't mean that they are equally fast).

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks for the comments. I can understand that the third term can be dropped. But why the forth and fifth terms can also be dropped?

Comment: @LinAlg - And that is why for performance critical computations it is best to use an optimized library like Intel MKL. I assume that the library would take into account the processor design and choosing the best strategy for linear algebra operations.

Comment: @user99015 taking the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables) and a slightly easier function to demonstrate that cross terms can be ignored: $f(x,y)=x^2+2xy+y^2$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^2+y^2)$: take $C=2$, $M=0$, then the condition is that $x^2+2xy+y^2 \leq 2(x^2+y^2)$ for all $(x,y)$ (which holds because it simplifies to $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$).